# Do Tiefling subrace stats/abilities replace the base?

Tags: tiefling

For instance; I am considering rolling a Mammon tiefling; I assume because it's ability score increase (+2 Cha and +1 Int) is the same as base nothing changes, but does Legacy of Minauros replace Infernal Legacy?

Comment: Do you mean the one [from the UA](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UA_FiendishOptions.pdf)? Are you talking about D&D fifth edition? Please specify the tag.

Comment: Hi and welcome to rpg.se! Check out our [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) and the help on [how to ask a good question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. You’ve done really well by adding in some of the detail there, but it can also help to signpost with the sources you’re drawing from, for one.